# How do I install Lync?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2013, lync

I just installed Office 2013 for Home and Business On Windows 7.  However Lync didn't get installed.  How do I install Lync?  I tried [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-lync-online-help/install-lync-HA102894720.aspx) but I don't have an Office 365 account.

Comment: I don't believe Office 2013 for Home and Business comes with Lync. The `Office 2013 for Home and Business` does not clearly indicate it comes with it.  As I thought.  Only`Office Professional Plus 2013` provides a license to the client.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/office-2010-volume-licensing-suites-comparison-FX101825637.aspx

Comment: Lync is not really designed to be used by single people. Lync Online is designed for small office. Lync on-premise for middle/big corporation. But if you really want to use Lync, an Office 365 account is mandatory. For best integration, you will also need to subscribe to Exchange online. Other than that, enterprise voice functionality are not available with Lync Online.